# I Don't Understand The Difference In These Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, moq, xunit, prism-4

I'm using Moq, xUnit and Prism 4.  My unit test's objective is to fire an event and confirm that a property has changed in my view model to match the value from the event.  This test, by the way, fails (*Expected:5, Actual:0*):

```
// Version One
[Fact]
public void Should_set_DayCount_on_DayCountChangedEvent()
{
    var eaMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
    eaMock.SetupCurriculumEvents(); // see below
    var vm = new CurriculumItemViewModel(eaMock.Object, _systemStatus.Object);
    vm.Load(_newItem);
    var dayCount = 5;

    eaMock.Object.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>().Publish(dayCount);

    Assert.Equal(dayCount, _vm.DayCount);
}
```

I got tired of setting up my event aggregator mock everywhere, so I created an extension method to do the dirty work for me:

```
public static void SetupCurriculumEvents(this Mock<IEventAggregator> eaMock)
{
     eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
         .Returns(new DayCountChangedNotification());

     // lots of other "notification" events here as well
}
```

Then I realized that I'm creating a new event every time it's retrieved from the mock event aggregator, so the `Subscribe()` on one instance (in the VM) isn't on the same instance as the `Publish(dayCount)` in my test.

Well, methinks, let's just always use the same object (by overwriting the extension method's `Setup()` for this event) and we're gonna be good:

```
// Version Two
[Fact]
public void Should_set_DayCount_on_DayCountChangedEvent()
{
    var dayCountChangedEvent = new DayCountChangedNotification();
    var eaMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
    eaMock.SetupCurriculumEvents(); // still need this for all the other events
    // overwrite the setup from the extension method
    eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
        .Returns(dayCountChangedEvent);

    var vm = new CurriculumItemViewModel(eaMock.Object, _systemStatus.Object);
    vm.Load(_newItem);

    var dayCount = 5;

    dayCountChangedEvent.Publish(dayCount);

    Assert.Equal(dayCount, _vm.DayCount);
}
```

... which also fails spectacularly.

For some reason, I decided to try refactoring the extension method, (and reverted the unit test back to Version One):

```
public static class MockingExtensions
{
    private static DayCountChangedNotification DayNotification = new DayCountChangedNotification();

    public static void SetupCurriculumEvents(this Mock<IEventAggregator> eaMock)
    {
         eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
         .Returns(DayNotification);

         // etc...
    }
}
```

... which to my mind, is basically the same thing - I'm always returning the same instance of the Event.

Here's the kicker:  *this test passes*.

That's great and everything, but I don't understand *why* it passes - and if I don't understand why it's passing, then I don't really know if it's right or not.

Accepted answer needs to explain *two* things:

1. Why does the refactored extension method with the static instance pass?
2. Why doesn't Version Two pass?

Comment: Declaring a static class field is not the same as a local variable. Did you run this test only or did you run this test during a test-run with other tests? What is the implementation of DayCountChangedNotification?

Comment: `DayCountChangedNotification` is just an empty class that inherits from Prism's `CompositePresentationEvent<int?>` class.  The test was run both as a single run and a joint run with other tests - results were consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and created the code below. All three tests succeeded so i think something is missing in the question. It is important to know that moqObject.Setup(...).Return(true) is not the same as moqObject.Setup(...).Return(() => true). See for more info [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqReturnLambda.aspx)

```
 namespace Test
 {
    using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events;
    using Moq;
    using System;
    using Xunit;

    // Moq    4.2.1510.2205
    // Prism  4.0.0.0
    // xunit  2.1.0

    public class CurriculumItemViewModel
    {
        public CurriculumItemViewModel(IEventAggregator agg)
        {
            agg.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>().Subscribe((int? x) => {
                DayCount = x.Value;
            });
        }

        public int DayCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class DayCountChangedNotification : CompositePresentationEvent<int?>
    {
        public DateTime Created = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        private static DayCountChangedNotification DayNotification = new DayCountChangedNotification();

        public static void SetupCurriculumEventsV1(this Mock<IEventAggregator> eaMock)
        {
            eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
                  .Returns(new DayCountChangedNotification());
        }

        public static void SetupCurriculumEventsV2(this Mock<IEventAggregator> eaMock)
        {
            eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
                  .Returns(DayNotification);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {     
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldSetDayCountOnDayCountChangedEvent1a()
        {
            // Arrange
            var dayCount = 5;
            var eaMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
            eaMock.SetupCurriculumEventsV1();

            var vm = new CurriculumItemViewModel(eaMock.Object);
            var notification = eaMock.Object.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>();
            var notification2 = eaMock.Object.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>();

            // Act
            notification.Publish(dayCount);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(dayCount, vm.DayCount);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ShouldSetDayCountOnDayCountChangedEvent2()
        {
            // Arrange
            var dayCount = 5;
            var eaMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
            eaMock.SetupCurriculumEventsV1();

            // This will override the setup done by SetupCurriculumEventsV1
            var notification = new DayCountChangedNotification();         
            eaMock.Setup(ea => ea.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>())
                  .Returns(notification);

            var vm = new CurriculumItemViewModel(eaMock.Object);

            // Act
            notification.Publish(dayCount);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(dayCount, vm.DayCount);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ShouldSetDayCountOnDayCountChangedEvent1b()
        {
            // Arrange
            var dayCount = 5;
            var eaMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();

            eaMock.SetupCurriculumEventsV2(); 

            var vm = new CurriculumItemViewModel(eaMock.Object);
            var notification = eaMock.Object.GetEvent<DayCountChangedNotification>();

            // Act
            notification.Publish(dayCount);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(dayCount, vm.DayCount);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer - give me a few days to poke through it and I'll let you know.